# Implementing a Generic Interface In Java

Tags: java, generics

I am new to Java Generics. I have to implement an interface which is of generic type. The syntax is as follows:

```
public interface A{}

public interface B<T extends A>{
    public T methodB(T a) ;
}
```

Now I have to implement B so Lets say my Class is C

```
public class C implements B<T extends A>{}
```

The java compiler is not letting me use it this way. Also I do not want to  use raw types. Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be

```
public class C<T extends A> implements B<T>
```

The type parameter is declared following the class name, and later can be used in the implements clause.

Answer (score 3):

If your implementing class is still a generic type you have to use this syntax:

```
public class C<T extends A> implements B<T> {}
```

As explained by **Eran**.

If `C` is not generic you simply need to specify the type argument for your interface:

```
public class C implements B<TypeExtendingA> {}
```

Where `TypeExtendingA` implements or extends `A` (or is `A`)

Comment: But will it not limit the scope?

Comment: It depends on what you actually need. If you need to have a generic implementation go for the first option...